# read multiple excel file and apply cleaning process on them

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple excel file in the same directory I need to read them and apply some cleaning processes on them and write the changes after the cleaning .is there any way to do this .because the there are many files and I will do the same process in each file and it takes times

```
 # Create the list of file names: 
filenames = ['tweets7.xlsx', 'tweets6.xlsx']

# Create the list for the three DataFrames you want to create:
dataframes = []
for filename in filenames:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(filename))

# Print top 5 rows of the 1st DataFrame in dataframes
print(dataframes[0].head(10))
```

I use this code and it works with me then I apply the cleaning process such as remove punctuation , link etc . when I save the cleaning by this code

```
dataframes['clean text'] = dataframes['Text'].apply(lambda x: processPost(x)) # apply used to call the method procssPost
```

the error appears

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Most of the times it's not the question "can it be done", but rather " what have you tried already".  please share some code/research  if you would like people to think with you